# Unable to create Central Inventory

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-10g

I'm trying to install Oracle 11g on Linux and have already configured the variables and X-host but can't able to create Central Inventory.

My Central Inventory location is `/u01/app/u0` and group name is `dba`.

It throw an error:

> error [INS-32033] Central Inventory location is not writable.

I have already tried `chmod 755`.

Comment: Who's the owner of the directory?

Comment: `oinstall` usually owns the inventory, I think

Comment: There's no one fix for this problem, but you can try : `chmod -R 770 <OracleInventory>` It would be very interesting to know what the ouput of that command is on your server.

Answer (score 3):

But the central inventory location should be /u01/app/oracle/oraInventory, not what you have. It is much better to follow the recommandations of Oracle for directories naming (see OFA section in installation guide).

check what is the id and the group of the user running the runInstaller, usually it is oracle:oinstall

then as user root

```
mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle
chown -R oracle:oinstall /u01/app/oracle (assuming oracle:oinstall)
```

before starting runInstaller make sure you don't have the env variable ORACLE_HOME set. You don't need to set ORACLE_BASE, but if you do then it should be pointing to /u01/app/oracle. So

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
```

If the env variable ORACLE_BASE is not set, Oracle is clever enough to recognize /u01/app/oracle as the standard ORACLE_BASE location

Note: as a side note, standardize the id of user oracle and the gid of groups oinstall and dba accross all your system, i.e use the same values everywhere.

Comment: I respect recommendations, but in the end one can choose the location of your central inventory, if one thinks it is smarter than the recommendation. It's not mandatory to choose the directory you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue you are facing.

solution was:

```
mkdir -p /u01/app/oraInventory
chown -R oracle:oinstall /u01/app/oraInventory
chmod -R 775 /u01/app/oraInventory
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when i tried to reinstall the 12c release 1 due to the fact that my file location was not well set.

My solution was to delete everything under the directory `/u01/app/oraInventory` after logging in as the root user

```
cd /u01/app/oraInventory

[root@student381 oraInventory]# ll
total 20
drwxrwx--- 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Nov 28 01:35 ContentsXML
drwxrwx--- 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Nov 27 23:46 logs
-rw-rw---- 1 oracle oinstall   64 Nov 28 01:35 oraInst.loc
-rwxrwx--- 1 oracle oinstall 1692 Nov 28 01:35 orainstRoot.sh
drwxrwx--- 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Nov 27 23:46 oui

[root@student381 oraInventory]# \rm -rf ./*
```

After removing all the directories and files
do:

```
./runInstaller
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
cd /u01/app/oraInventory

drwxrwx--- 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Nov 28 01:35 ContentsXML
drwxrwx--- 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Nov 27 23:46 logs
-rw-rw---- 1 oracle oinstall   64 Nov 28 01:35 oraInst.loc
-rwxrwx--- 1 oracle oinstall 1692 Nov 28 01:35 orainstRoot.sh
drwxrwx--- 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Nov 27 23:46 oui

[root@student381 oraInventory]# \rm -rf ./*
```

Answer (score 0):

It's neither a permission nor directory/files issue. The only requirement is to have the below file exist and have below entry in it.

```
cat /etc/oraInst.loc

inventory_loc=your_inventory_location
inst_group=dba
```

In my case inventory_loc was /sgss/app/oraInventory. Under this  only the files/folders will be created and it doesn't matter how many binaries you install, the inventory.xml will add all the entries for your binary installation.

---> Only need to ensure /etc/oraInst.loc exist which is validated by installer.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 ContentsXML]$ cat inventory.xml

<!-- Do not modify the contents of this file by hand. -->
<HOME_LIST
<HOME NAME="OraDB19Home1" LOC="/sgss/app/oracle/product/19300" TYPE="O" IDX="1"
<HOME NAME="OraDB19Home2" LOC="/sgss/app/oracle/product/19140" TYPE="O" IDX="2"
<HOME NAME="OraDB19Home3" LOC="/sgss/app/oracle/product/19120" TYPE="O"
```

I have edited the above file content just to show you multiple entry of binaries of different versions successfully installed when we have /etc/oraInst.loc.

Answer (score -3):

i had this problem and when I look on the mentioned path, I saw oracle previous unsuccess installation had created those folder.
so just delete the folder and try again

Comment: This doesn't seem to add  anything to the existing answers.